# Is it possible to download all of my photos on facebook through facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to download all of my photos and albums from facebook in a programatic way.

I know its possible to push photos to fb through graph api. I was wondering if it is possible to pull photos as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. First you would have to get all the albums:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=

Then you would have to request the list of photos in each album:

https://graph.facebook.com/album_Id_here/photos?access_token=

The result of the last request will give you a JSON object that contains urls of each photo in the album.

See the documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It might be worth noting you can quickly get an access token via the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: I wrote a Python script to pull down all the owner of the access_token's Facebook albums.  It should demonstrate the functionality fairly well and *nix based OSes should be able to use it as is.  

[get_albums.py](https://github.com/mhowsden/get_albums.py)